# Iterating over user user defined collections in Apache came route

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel, apache-camel-cdi

I got a requirement that i have on main route and child route. In the main route will get the list of objects, there i need to make a call to child route for each individual elements in the list. 
Then in Child route will make a call to web-service by appending that element as one of the parameter.

Code:

```
from("direct:SupplierRoute")
                .choice()
                .when(header(IS_SUPPLIER_AVAILABLE).isEqualTo(true))
                .split(body())
                .parallelProcessing()
                .streaming()
                .to("direct:SUPGetHotelAggregatorRatesRQ")
                .bean(parallelProcessingRequestProcessor)
                .end()
                .end()
                .end();
 from("direct:SUPGetHotelAggregatorRatesRQ")
                .process(startOperation(DISTRIBUTION, GET_HOTEL_AGGREGATOR_RATES_API_GENERATE_VM_REQUEST))
                .to("velocity:velocity/GetHotelAggregatorRatesRQToGetHotelSupplierRatesRQ.vm")
                .process(endOperation(DISTRIBUTION, GET_HOTEL_AGGREGATOR_RATES_API_GENERATE_VM_REQUEST))
                .end();
```

I'm setting the value to the exchange body as below,

```
 public static final List<HotelRefs.HotelRef> supplierHotelRefs = new ArrayList();
 exchange.getIn().setBody(supplierHotelRefs);
```

But the above code sample was not working,If anyone let us know if there is any approach in camel to iterate over user defined collections at route level.

Thanks,
Raghavan

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific what is not working. And what version of Camel do you use? The splitter EIP should split over that ArrayList for each element.

Answer (score 0):

Put a log statement after the Splitter and run the code.

```
.split(body())
.log("How many log lines do you receive?")
```

If you get just one log line, the Splitter does not work as expected. You could then try to use another Camel version.

If you get as many log lines as your ArrayList contains elements, the iteration works fine and you've got another problem. You should then find out the real problem and ask a new question.

If you get no log line at all, your condition in `when` is not satisfied.